# Printing a question mark after a loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Trying to figure out how to print the question mark as so: 
 user inputs: "apple" and then the string gets stored in an array and gets printed like this : "apple?" 
 here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[23];
    int i=0;
    printf("enter a single english word: ");
    while( (a[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' && i < 23){
        a[i] = '\0';
        i = 0;
    }
    while(a[i] != '\0'){
       printf("%c",a[i++]);
    }  
    printf("?");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are resetting i after each read. why?

Comment: I suspect he meant to do that after the loop was done.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting i after each character read. That is effectively making you erase whatever was stored. you need to move `i = 0;` from inside the first while loop to just after it.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have inside the first `while` loop should be done after the loop is done. You do all the work of the loop in the `while()` header. The loop body was resetting `i` back to `0` each time, so you were repeatedly overwriting the first character of `a`.

```
while( (a[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' && i < 23){
}
a[i] = '\0';
i = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your input loop is incorrect. It should be like so:

```
while( (a[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' && i < 23) {}
a[i] = '\0';
```

As the comments to your question say above, you are resetting the pointer index after each character is read, therefore reading character 0 of the array every time. You should do this after the loop.

Also, because `a` is just a string, you should be able to just print it like this (without the loop):

```
printf("%s?", a);
```

---

Final Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[23];
    int i=0;
    printf("enter a single english word: ");
    while( (a[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' && i < 23) {}
    a[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s?",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The follwoing logic works:

```
char a[23];
int i=0,j=0;
printf("enter a single english word: ");
```

To scan the input into an array :

```
for(a[i]=getchar(); (a[i]!='\n') && (i<23) ; i++)
        ;
```

And finally printing :

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        putchar(a[j]);
```

Hence the program :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[23];
    int i=0,j=0;
    printf("enter a single english word: ");

    for(a[i]=getchar(); (a[i]!='\n') && (i<23) ; i++)
        ;

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        putchar(a[j]);

    printf("?");
    return 0;
}
```